# Under thermal equilibrium, spin stay still or oscillate?

Tags: quantum-spin, equilibrium

Under thermal equilibrium, spin stay still or oscillate?
For atoms with inertia, atoms will keep moving even the net forces are zero, they will oscillate with velocities.  But spin does not have inertia, if the net effective magnetic field (perpendicular part) is zero, the spin will not precess. Hoever, the spin wave excitation at finite temperature means the spin will precess.  Are there any experiments that show the spin states at thermal equilibrium?

Comment: is this in the context of ferromagnetism? https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-46035-7_1

Comment: How would the system reach equilibrium if the spins were frozen in place?